# change when accordion opens and close

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```js
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
});

$(function () {
    $(".details-toggle").click(function () {
        $(".edit-toggle").text("(read more)");
        $(".ui-state-active").find(".edit-toggle").text("read less");
    });
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        header: "h3",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="" href="#collapse1">Over mezelf, Rachid Baitar </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" >
        <div class="panel-body">Ik ben doctor in de psychologie, relatie-, gezin- en systeempsychotherapeut, klinisch psycholoog, bemiddelaar van relationele conflicten, gastdocent en vooral mens.

Vanuit mijn liefde voor de complexiteit van het leven en relaties tussen mensen heb ik een grondige ervaring opgebouwd als psychotherapeut en psycholoog.
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Opleiding (read more) </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="dolessmore">

        <div class="panel-body">Mijn master in de Klinische Psychologie bekwam ik na studies aan de Katholieke Universiteit van Leuven en Universiteit van Leeds (Verenigd Koninkrijk). In deze opleiding lag de focus op hoe inzichten over het innerlijk leven en uiterlijk gedrag ingezet konden worden ter verlichting van iemands’ psychische spanningen, angsten en depressies. Verder bouwde ik ervaring op over hoe gedachten, gevoelens en gedrag over verschillende levensfasen al dan niet kunnen bijdragen tot de geestelijke gezondheid van mensen.

Later volgde ik nog een bijkomende universitaire specialisatie tot Bemiddelaar van Conflicten en Familiezaken (KULeuven) en een 4-jarige vorming tot Relatie- Gezin- en Systheempsychotherapeut (KULeuven). Binnen beide opleidingen was de basisfilosofie dat het persoonlijke van een mens onlosmakelijk verbonden is met de wederzijdse invloeden tussen mensen en de vele veranderlijke leefwerelden waarin deze plaatsvinden. Therapie voor menselijke problemen is soms ook samen zoeken naar hoe belangrijke relationele, familiale, sociale en economische betekenissen zinvol bespreekbaar kunnen worden.

<br ><br >Een interuniversitair project van de Katholieke Universiteit Leuven en de Universiteit van Gent bracht me ertoe om een doctoraatsonderzoek in de psychologie uit te voeren. Ik heb me intensief kunnen verdiepen in wat de helpende processen tijdens bemiddeling zijn en hoe kwaliteitsvolle scheidingsregelingen bekomen worden.
</div>
              </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Ervaring in praktijk (read more)</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Om kwaliteitsvolle therapie te bieden vind ik het belangrijk opleiding te verbinden met praktijk. Hiertoe deed ik elf jaar geleden een klinische stage aan het Centrum voor Geestelijke Gezondheidszorg te Leuven. Ik heb eveneens gedurende verscheidene jaren een assistentschap als therapeut opgenomen in het Centrum voor Relatie en Gezinstherapie (UZ Gasthuisberg). Thans ben ik als klinisch psycholoog en psychotherapeut verbonden aan het Centrum voor Geestelijke Gezondheidszorg Vlaams-Brabant Oost (CGG-VBO) alsook het PsychoTherapie Centrum (PTC) te Overijse.<br ><br > Ik neem regelmatig deel aan twee verschillende intervisiegroepen, seminaries  en doe beroep op supervisie om voeling te houden met nieuwe ontwikkelingen en blijvend een professionele aanpak te kunnen bieden.
 
Tot slot ben ik erkend door de <a href="https://www.compsy.be/sites/default/files/getuigschriften/getuigschrift_19525_1486557567.pdf"> psychologencommissie  (erkenningsnummer 801115985)</a>. Houdt in dat vertrouwelijkheid en beroepsgeheim alsook een gedegen basisopleiding, praktijkervaring en een permanente bijscholing de ethische pilaren vormen van mijn psychotherapiepraktijk.
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

I tried several scripts to change text from my bootstrap accordion.
What I want is:
When the user presses the accordion with name "intro (click to read more)" and it opens the text should change to "intro (click for less)" or something like that. and when you click to close it should change back to "Intro (click to read more)" I use bootstrap accordions if it makes any difference.
[here is screenshot how the accordions look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLs73.png)

Thanks in advance.

This is the code i have in my aspx file

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="" href="#collapse1">Over mezelf, Rachid Baitar </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" >
        <div class="panel-body">Ik ben doctor in de psychologie, relatie-, gezin- en systeempsychotherapeut, klinisch psycholoog, bemiddelaar van relationele conflicten, gastdocent en vooral mens.

Vanuit mijn liefde voor de complexiteit van het leven en relaties tussen mensen heb ik een grondige ervaring opgebouwd als psychotherapeut en psycholoog.
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Opleiding (Lees verder) </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="dolessmore">

        <div class="panel-body">Mijn master in de Klinische Psychologie bekwam ik na studies aan de Katholieke Universiteit van Leuven en Universiteit van Leeds (Verenigd Koninkrijk). In deze opleiding lag de focus op hoe inzichten over het innerlijk leven en uiterlijk gedrag ingezet konden worden ter verlichting van iemands’ psychische spanningen, angsten en depressies. Verder bouwde ik ervaring op over hoe gedachten, gevoelens en gedrag over verschillende levensfasen al dan niet kunnen bijdragen tot de geestelijke gezondheid van mensen.

Later volgde ik nog een bijkomende universitaire specialisatie tot Bemiddelaar van Conflicten en Familiezaken (KULeuven) en een 4-jarige vorming tot Relatie- Gezin- en Systheempsychotherapeut (KULeuven). Binnen beide opleidingen was de basisfilosofie dat het persoonlijke van een mens onlosmakelijk verbonden is met de wederzijdse invloeden tussen mensen en de vele veranderlijke leefwerelden waarin deze plaatsvinden. Therapie voor menselijke problemen is soms ook samen zoeken naar hoe belangrijke relationele, familiale, sociale en economische betekenissen zinvol bespreekbaar kunnen worden.

<br ><br >Een interuniversitair project van de Katholieke Universiteit Leuven en de Universiteit van Gent bracht me ertoe om een doctoraatsonderzoek in de psychologie uit te voeren. Ik heb me intensief kunnen verdiepen in wat de helpende processen tijdens bemiddeling zijn en hoe kwaliteitsvolle scheidingsregelingen bekomen worden.
</div>
              </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Ervaring in praktijk (Lees verder)</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Om kwaliteitsvolle therapie te bieden vind ik het belangrijk opleiding te verbinden met praktijk. Hiertoe deed ik elf jaar geleden een klinische stage aan het Centrum voor Geestelijke Gezondheidszorg te Leuven. Ik heb eveneens gedurende verscheidene jaren een assistentschap als therapeut opgenomen in het Centrum voor Relatie en Gezinstherapie (UZ Gasthuisberg). Thans ben ik als klinisch psycholoog en psychotherapeut verbonden aan het Centrum voor Geestelijke Gezondheidszorg Vlaams-Brabant Oost (CGG-VBO) alsook het PsychoTherapie Centrum (PTC) te Overijse.<br ><br > Ik neem regelmatig deel aan twee verschillende intervisiegroepen, seminaries  en doe beroep op supervisie om voeling te houden met nieuwe ontwikkelingen en blijvend een professionele aanpak te kunnen bieden.

Tot slot ben ik erkend door de <a href="https://www.compsy.be/sites/default/files/getuigschriften/getuigschrift_19525_1486557567.pdf"> psychologencommissie  (erkenningsnummer 801115985)</a>. Houdt in dat vertrouwelijkheid en beroepsgeheim alsook een gedegen basisopleiding, praktijkervaring en een permanente bijscholing de ethische pilaren vormen van mijn psychotherapiepraktijk.
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: where is the code for changing text?

Comment: I removed it, i searched it on google and stackoverflow but it didn't work so i removed it

Comment: create a fiddle so that we can check and rectify. with your provided code we could do nothing

Comment: oh thanks for the tip, i'll search for the code i used and make a fiddle

Comment: I've updated the post with the JS script that i used, i don't know a lot about JS tbh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't know what you want exactly, bootstrap accordion or read more/less link or read more/less in bootstrap accordion.  however i created a snippet have a look ,might help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fulltext').hide();

    $('.blog-item .readmore').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().find('.fulltext').slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Read less...' ? 'Read more...' : 'Read less...');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blog-item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at urna ac
        leo vulputate egestas a ut odio. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec
        in erat velit, eu ultricies diam. 
        
    </p>
        <p class='fulltext'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at urna ac
            leo vulputate egestas a ut odio. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>
    <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more...</a>
</div>
```

Comment: this is what i wanted, but i can't figger out how to use it in my version

Comment: What version? What you want?

Comment: i want your script for my bootstrap accordion

Comment: Wait give me some time ,I'll prepare in a while

Comment: You want the same you shared in a picture?